# Is there a better way to get the contentsize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, lifecycle

so here is my problem, I have a scrollview contains some subview with some dynamic contents which related to the layout. And I want to set the scrollview's contentsize exactly is the sum of the subview's size.

In a word rootview->scrollview->some subview with dynamic contents(let's say a mulitilines UILabel)

so here is what I did:

according to the document in viewDidLayoutSubviews, this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view’s subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.

So my UILabel didn't layout when this method happens.

then In the viewdidappear I set the contentSize, but a new problem is this problem didn't active when we switch to landscape, so I did the setting both in the viewDidLayoutSubview and viewdidappear.

My question is 
1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Where is the exactly moment the root view's subview finish their subviewlayout, and how to get into it?(subclass it seems a little heavy)

I'm using autolayout and constraint in ios7, and I have tried setviewNeedLayout and layoutifneeded in the viewwilllayoutsubviews, which didn't work.

And put layoutifneeded in the viewdidlayoutsubviews will crash when switch the orientation

here is some code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self adjustScrollViewContentSize];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self adjustScrollViewContentSize];
}

- (void)adjustScrollViewContentSize
{
    UIView *bottomUIView = [self getBottomUIView];
    CGRect superRect = [bottomUIView convertRect:bottomUIView.bounds toView:self.scrollView];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, superRect.origin.y + superRect.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AutoLayout, you should be able add constraints such that you don't need to manually update the contentSize - the scrollView will adjust it itself based on the size of its contents.

The key is to ensure you have internal constraints that attach internal subviews to all 4 internal edges of the scrollview. For example, using Visual Format Language:

- Horizontally:   `|[myLabel]|`
- Vertically:    `V:|[myLabel]-[someOtherLabel]|`

Essentially, as long as you have unambiguous constraints attaching the left edge to the right edge via your subviews (and the same for top to bottom), then the scrollview will infer its contentSize from those.

Comment: I think this didn't work for me, I want my subview in the scrollview's relative position didn't move relative to the screen.
I